# jQuery $.get() not working, returns status 200 without errors, yet no response on client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I'm trying to send a `GET` request to a server to get a message. I used the jQuery `$.get()` method and it successfully reached the server.

However, I cannot send a `res` back to the client. What am I doing wrong?

```
// client side:
$.get("localhost:3000/load", function (data) {
    console.log("message from sever");  // is not logged
    console.log(data);                  // also is not logged
});

// server side:
app.get("/load", function (req, res) {
    console.log("Am I arrived in server?");  // appears in console
    res.end("hey");
});
```

Comment: Try targeting `http://localhost:3000/load` on the client side.

Comment: what are you getting in network tab in developer tool ?

Comment: I tried http//: but no change

Comment: Try adding a callback on res.end

Comment: Everytime I clicked button, 200 ok is all i get

Comment: In Chrome's console, running your exact jQuery code returns a cross-site request warning. What does the console return for you?

Comment: Chrome's consle returns nothing and in network tab 200 ok.
Remote Address:[::1]:3000
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/load
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Comment: x.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery.min.js:6
x.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:6
x.each.x.(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:6
(anonymous function) @ (index):56

Comment: have you tried send instead of end?

Comment: @LouisaBuchanan I just did and still no response...

Comment: Hmm, try setting the content type and then sending the response: `res.type('text/plain');` `res.send('hey');`

Comment: @StuartWagner I can see the word "hey" in "localhost:3000/load" page but stil no console log..

Comment: You'll have to show us more of your code so we can get a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: @StuartWagner Your right. but something strange is that I just found that if I use "res.send", msg are comming with no log. It's strange. anyway I can get msg from sever because of your help.
I really really appreciate it. Thanks dude!

Comment: @KimCrab Cool, glad you're on the right track now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already accessing localhost:3000, then drop it from the request...

```
$.get("/load", function (data) {
    console.log("message from sever");  // is not logged
    console.log(data);                  // also is not logged
});
```

...if you're not accessing localhost:3000, you'll need to add the `http://`

```
$.get("http://localhost:3000/load", function (data) {
    console.log("message from sever");  // is not logged
    console.log(data);                  // also is not logged
});
```

Otherwise you will get the following error (in Google Chrome)...

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:3000/load. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

Comment: Can you add the code that wraps the `$.get`?  This is working for me on both the client and server.